# I am using Date Axes Renderer, When there is only one point the graph canvas is plotted, with the x axis tick but the y axis value is not shown

Tags: jqgrid, jqplot

---

I am using Date Axes Renderer When there is only one data the graph is
plotted, with the x axis tick but the y axis value is not shown !
Please help me out ! Below is my code :-

```
function plotgraph(data)
{
var mydata = [];
             var dateticks = [];
             $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                 var date = formatdate(data[index].TextColumnString);
                 dateticks.push([date]);
                 mydata.push([date, s]);
             });


                 $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
             plot1 = $.jqplot('newgraph', [mydata], {
                 title: 'Revenue',
                 legend: { show: true, location: 'ne' },
                 grid: {
                     drawBorder:false,
                     borderWidth: null,
                     background: '#ffffff',
                     gridLineColor: '#e0e0e0',
                     shadow:false
                 },
                 axes:
               {
                   xaxis:
                       {
                           label: 'Dates',
                           numberTicks: dateticks.length,
                           ticks:dateticks,
                           renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                           tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                           tickOptions:{
                                        fontSize: '10px',
                                        fontFamily: 'Arial',
                                        angle:-30
                                        },


                       },
                       yaxis: { label: 'Revenue(in $)', autoscale:true,
                                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                                tickOptions: { formatString: '$%.2f'} }
                   },
                    series:[
                       { showLabel: true, lineWidth: 3.5, label:
'Revenue', markerOptions: { style: 'circle'}}],
                   highlighter    : { show : true, sizeAdjust : 7.5},
                   cursor         : { show : false }
               });

         }
     }
//this function is used to format the date from the given to required format.
     function formatdate(date) {
         var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
         date = date.replace(',', '');
         var fdate = date.split(' ');
         var day = fdate[0];
         var month = months.indexOf(fdate[1], 0);
         month = Number(month) + 1;
         var year = fdate[2];
         var mydate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
         return mydate;
     }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Above Code is running good for data array having more than 1 point !

Comment: This Above code is retrieving data from server-side, with a filter to be sent as a parameter to be retrieved. Now if the filter for data aims at vast data range i.e more data points then the graph works perfectly but when the filter is strict and there is only one data point returned then this fails to plot the data .

Comment: Was this resolved? I'm having the same problem where the graph breaks when there is only one plot point.